# How to find successive positions in the Matrix?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have matrix like :

```
int TempMap[3][3] =
{
    {1,0,0},
    {0,1,0},
    {1,0,0},
};
```

I update matrix index on changes from 0 to 1.

Now how do I find that I have '1' in 3 successive positions.

**Update:**

and also check if its on cross line like :

```
{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
 int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] == 1)
                counter++;
            else
                counter = 0;
            if(counter == 3) {
                NSLog(@"3 successive '1'");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is its on {0,0},{1,1},{2,2} than its not working.